# should I be using 1.9.2 or 1.8.7 for rails 3.0 production apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using 1.9.2 with rails 3, and I ran into a snag with ruby-debug.

Should I be using 1.8.7 to be more on the safe side with rails 3?

I'm new to rails, and I want to stay away from hackish workarounds or configuration nightmares.

(I'm using rvm)

Comment: who is your production server?

Answer (score 0):

The best in performance is ruby 1.9.2. But ruby 1.8.7 is stable too. So you can use both.